# Started using UUID's as primary key, would like to execute union of entities with BigSerial Primary Key

Tags: postgresql, union, uuid

Some of my newer tables are now using UUID type fields as PKey and older tables are still using `bigserial`. I have several tables (let's call them entities) I would like to query returning the primary key in the result (using a UNION). What is the most efficient way to return the entity_id's? I am assuming a simple CAST would do the trick, but this is to handle a sitewide search which requires it to be as quick as possible.

```
    select entityA.a_id::TEXT as entity_id from entityA
    union
    select entityB.b_uuid::TEXT as entity_id from entityB
    union
    select entityC.c_id::TEXT as entity_id from entityC
    union
    select entityD.d_id::TEXT as entity_id from entityD
    union
    select EntityE.e_id::Text as entity_id from EntityE
```

Any recommendations?

Comment: Casting to text should not add too much overhead - you can easily try it by comparing the execution times on the same subset (one with UUIDs, one with bigints) with and without casting.

Answer (score 1):

Casting to text should not add much overhead, however you may want to consider using `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION` if you're looking for performance (UNION attempts to filtering duplicates).